# Select window unable to select Childwindow

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In My JavaCode , After clicking on Edit Description link a window get opens (i.e. Java Script Window) Images here 1st one gives anchor tag with attributes and 2nd one is opened window

Image 1:: [image]

Image 2:: Window image Along with Page Source here
[image]

What i need is A. Select the window open(java script) B. Enter the text into Text Area and click Ok.

control is waiting infinite @ Select Window key word its not moving forward. I have to kill Control forcefully.

Here is the code

```
package Bala.AutoPratice.module1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class WindowSwitch {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\bin\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("http://10.1.111.165/Login.aspx");
        //To check if we have landed in the correct place
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginName")).sendKeys("User1");
        driver.findElement(By.id("Password")).sendKeys("User1@123");
        driver.findElement(By.id("LoginBtn")).click();

        driver.get("http://10.1.111.165/roles.aspx");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"NewBtn\"]/span")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"aspnetForm\"]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/a")).click();

        String MainWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();
        Set<String> s1=driver.getWindowHandles();       
        Iterator<String> i1=s1.iterator();      

        while(i1.hasNext())         
        {       
            String ChildWindow=i1.next();       

            if(!MainWindow.equalsIgnoreCase(ChildWindow))           
            {           
                   // Switching to Child window
                    driver.switchTo().window(ChildWindow);  // HERE IT NEVER SELECTS                                                                                                           
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"descript\"]")).sendKeys("gadddn@gmail.com");                         
                    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"myform\"]/div/input[1]")).click();           

            // Closing the Child Window.
                        driver.close();     
            }       
        }       
        // Switching to Parent window i.e Main Window.
            driver.switchTo().window(MainWindow);   


        driver.quit();



    }



}
```

If i use this

```
Alert myAlert = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
        myAlert.sendKeys("I_am_bbk");
        myAlert.accept();
```

I am getting  this error

```
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such alert' (400 expected)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'HIBAWL56712', ip: '10.158.126.17', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities
```

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: okay will follow the guide lines thanks for prompting me

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty clear from your snapshot that the window which gets opened is a *JavaScript* window i.e. an *Alert*. To enter some text into the *Text Area* and click *Ok* you can use the following block of code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.Alert;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
//other code
Alert myAlert = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
myAlert.sendKeys("I_am_bbk");
myAlert.accept();
driver.quit();
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting below error it says no such alert.(Below is the error). I think still its considering it as window..

Comment: Jan 29, 2018 12:20:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'no such alert' (400 expected)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for alert to be present (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'HIBAWL56712', ip: '10.158.126.17', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_151'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.Fi